# How do I add a button to the Sitecore Launchpad?

Tags: launchpad

I have installed XBlog for Sitecore 9. It shows up as an application on my Sitecore Launchpad.

I would also like to add the XBlog Importer to the Sitecore Launchpad. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm going to clean up your question just a bit. Your primary question is: How do I add a button to the Launch Pad.

Answer (score 6):

Adding Buttons to the Launch Pad is super easy. This will be a quick step by step.  The icons on the Launch Pad are driven by SPEAK which is driven by items in the Core Database.

### Adding an Icon to Launch Pad

1) Open up Desktop and change from "master" database to "core" database.

2) Open up Content Editor in Desktop and navigate to the Launchpad App.

[image]

3) The Buttons item (#1) is the parent item that contains all of the buttons on the Launch Pad.

4) The "Marketing" item (#2) is a section divider. This specifies which column/grouping on the Launch Pad the icon will show up.

5) The "ECM" item (#3) is considered a button example.

[image]

6) So, once you identify which section divider you want your icon in, right click on the #2 level item and add an item of from the template type of `/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Templates/LaunchPad-Button`.

7) Fill out the information as shown below:

[image]

Title: This is the text that will show up on the LaunchPad

Icon: This is the icon that will be used.

Link: This is the link that the click will go to.

OpenInNewTab: Opens in a new browser tab is checked.

OpenInIframe: Will open in an iframe window.

8) Save your item, and flip back to the master database, and then go back to the Launch Pad, and you're new item will show up.